balance package makes lineskip uneven (shorten distance between two lines)
Consider the following code:
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[auto-lang=false]{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\begin{document}
%\balance
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

Output:

Notice where the column break lies in (Lorem). Now uncomment %\balance line:

You see the problem? That distance between the baselines are shorter than that in the surrounding lines.

Suppose external constraints prevent me from using \usepackage{multicol} or \usepackage{flushend} as suggested in How to balance last page of two-column layout?. What option do I have?

spacing - Balance package messes up vertical space between lines in second column - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange appears to be the same question, but it got closed for some reason.

Replace  \usepackage{balance with \usepackage{flushend} (and remove \balance)

Given that it's likely the issue is with the two columns first being chopped up then concatenated, the obvious way out appears to be to avoid the columns being chopped up in the first place.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[auto-lang=false]{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\begin{document}
\balance
\vsize=2\vsize  % <<<<< IMPORTANT <<<<<
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

Insert \vsize=2\vsize somewhere in the first column of the last page, but make sure it's not close to the start (so the page should be ejected by the output routine before the command is executed).
Equivalently, use \setlength{\vsize}{2\vsize}.
Maybe one of the methods in header footer - How can I add "page # of ##" on my document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange can be used to automatically determine where the "first column of last page", but I haven't figured it out yet. (If anyone have an automated solution, please post it.)
